# How did the Phoenix land?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-first-contact

We see how the Phoenix was launched, and that its flight was successful - however it doesn't look like it would survive re-entry (no heat shield etc and we have no mention of deflector shields being part of its design) so how was the flight to end? Eject the forward section and land it like an Apollo capsule?

Is there anything in canon or the expanded universe which tells us how Cochrane got it back on the ground?

Edit: so it looks like there are heat tiles on the side of the forward cockpit, on the opposite side from the crew windows - however, they dont extend all the way done the fuselage so that might indicate that just the crew cabin is returned to earth.

However, that would mean that the guts of the Phoenix would be left in orbit - not a great situation if you want a continued program, especially considering the dialog suggests a lot of the basic structural material was very hard to get hold of.

Would love some corroboration on this.

Comment: Why would you assume it would be left in orbit?   Actually, in this case, why would it ever be in orbit at all?   A much easier manoeuver would be to eject in such a way that the remaining portion burns up in the atmosphere.

Comment: @ThePopMachine that line of thinking doesn't exactly change the point of my question - the bulk of the new fangled warp engine is actually in the portion that doesn't return to Earth, so having it left in orbit is "best case scenario" for re-use if just the crew compartment is landing.  It seems the "goal" did not include follow on flights but rather a single flight and abandonment, with anything following on just in "currently a dream" state.

Comment: Yeah, hence just a comment.   But actually, the more I think about it, this is a much easier manoeuver when you have you have warp or impulse drive.   The hard part about landing or splashing down is getting from orbitral velocity to zero groundspeed.   If you can just instantly get your velocity to zero groundspeed without starting at orbital velocity or never having been at orbital velocity at all, then you can just drop down with a parachute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm struggling to find a [fully canon source](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/lcars24.php) but the general gist is that the front section separates from the remainder of the rocket and becomes a landing module.

[John Eaves](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/John_Eaves), Concept Illustrator for the First Contact film has described the front section as a "capsule".

[image]

The image above tallies nicely with the on-screen image seen in the film.

[image]

Picard run his hands over the lower fuselage of the Phoenix (the bit that's going to be abandoned in orbit) and states that he remembers the ship from seeing it in the Smithsonian.

> **DATA:** *It is an historical irony that Doctor Cochrane would use an instrument of mass-destruction to inaugurate an era of peace.*
>
> (Picard feels the Titan V rocket)
>
> **PICARD:** *It's a boyhood fantasy, Data. I must have seen this ship hundreds of times in the Smithsonian, but I was never able to touch
> it.*

Assuming the ship's body was jettisoned in space it would have been a simple matter to ask our new Vulcan friends to recover it for us, as described in the Official Star Trek Fact Files.

> ...the
> PHOENIX is ready
> to make the
> historic jump to
> warp speed. Later,
> Cochrane's ship is
> retrieved and put
> on display in the
> Smithsonian.
>
> <sub><sup>[Official Star Trek Fact File - File 33, Card #3 - *"The Phoenix"*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Fact_Files)</sup></sub>

Comment: -1 for calling Vulcans "friends"

Comment: @DVK - They didn't become unfriendly until a few weeks later, after the hangover wore off.

Comment: So basically, it looks like it was a one shot deal? That seems ... short sighted.

Comment: @Moo - Not really. It costs a lot to make the first of something and [almost nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_economics#Information_goods) to make the second one.

Comment: @Moo: It was the first prototype, so it made sense to concentrate more on making it work than on bringing back the entire ship. Every crewed mission we've launched from 1961 to 2014 has abandoned substantial portions of the spacecraft -- probably more than 90% for everything other than the Space Shuttle (and Cochrane didn't have the resources to build a Shuttle-like craft).

Comment: @Richard that depends entirely on the production environment - I can't find the reference to cite as I can't find a final version of the script, but Lily Sloane does outright say that some of the materials were very difficult to get hold of, so yes in an ideal world I would agree with you but we aren't in an ideal world in this instance. So abandoning the "good stuff" in orbit is a little short sighted imho :)

Comment: @KeithThompson every crewed mission we have launched thus far has been part of a government backed, multi billion dollar programme, not the result of a few people in the backwaters of nowhere after a global war. Slight difference there ;) so I'm slightly doubtful that there was any follow on programme possible, due to the environment Cochran et al lived in at the time. The only reason there was was down to the alien contact, and that couldn't be planned...

Comment: @Moo - If it worked, you could reasonably expect the world to beat a path to your door. Getting hold of materials for attempt two would be child's play.

Comment: @Moo: Yes, Cochrane was operating without government backing -- which means that he had even fewer of the resources needed to build a SSTO (single stage to orbit) craft. At least with current technology, SSTO is likely to be cheaper in the long run, but vastly more expensive for a single launch. And he started with an exiting ICBM (built with government backing, BTW), which wasn't designed for reuse anyway.

Comment: The booster could have been retrieved and brought back  any time between the launch and the time Picard saw it in the Smithsonian. We wouldn't have had to ask the Vulcans to retrieve it.

Comment: @KeithThompson I dint disagree with any of that, but theres no indication any ongoing program is possible as we are given the impression that it was the Vulcan contact which acted as the kick up the arse the human race needed, not jut Cochrans flight. At the start of the film the impression is that the worlds governments have failed after the nuclear war, and that Cochran and Lily were working essentially alone, bartering with other camps to get what they needed.

Comment: @Moo: Cochrane's main motivation was money. If the Vulcans hadn't shown up, I think the Phoenix would have been a proof of concept that would have encouraged some government to pay for a more sustainable program.

Comment: Actually, the novel has Zephram Cochrane getting some financial backing from Indonesia, so he isn't entirely private. That' not included in the film though.

Comment: As a meta comment, some of the above comments (and possibly the answer itself) are amusing in light of what SpaceX  achieved since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

The main fuselage with the warp drive was recovered years latter and reunited with the capsule and sent to the Smithsonian . This is how Picard was able to see it but not touch it in the future

Comment: welcome! This would be a good answer with a source :)

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific and as NK Campbell said, you need evidence from a source to back your answer up.

Answer (score -1):

It is stated in the film that the Phoenix is in a museum, so burning up isn't an option. Also, it is made out of a highly advanced nuclear bomb. I'd hate to think what that would do to add to the nuclear contamination.
It is also almost impossible for everything to be burned up.

Look at all the space junk we've deorbited. A lot of that ends up in a place called Point Nemo. It's considered the furthest point on the Earth away from anywhere.

The Phoenix was made out of an advanced ICBM, which enters orbit of the Earth and then deorbits to blow up over or impact a particular point on Earth.

My betting is the original ICBM was designed to reenter the Earth and didn't need any extra equipment.

Comment: This seems like little better than guesswork. Can you offer any evidence to back this up?

Answer (score -1):

The lower part of the Phoenix could have been recreated for the Smithsonian, regardless. Picard also might have never realized that parts in the Smithsonian must have been recreations. And now, with the ability of the boosters to return to earth, it may have simply had a reentry heat shield and thruster packs with the ability to land as the boosters do today.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  "Recreated" is not the same as "landed" though, so I'm not sure this actually answers the question.

Comment: There's also no canon or the expanded universe evidence here -- like the question asked for -- just speculation.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure of the orbital mechanics involved, but is it possible the Phoenix did a direct departure, not actually entering orbit?  Instead of a reentry from orbital velocity it would be a free fall from space.  Still not easy, but certainly not a mach 25 slow down like we're used to seeing.

Comment: Can you add some details, and maybe a quote to this? It seems to be speculative, but adding some links would give it plausibility.

Comment: Either way, they've still got to land. How did that happen?

Comment: Our current spacecraft use aerobraking to slow down from orbital velocity. With reactionless engines, not having to worry about carrying enough fuel, the ship should be able to slow down enough to not need heat protection.

Answer (score -2):

Phoenix was never shown landing. 
However, John Eaves, Chief concept artist for Star Trek's many series, In his art book it depicts a flight pattern chart that shows the Phoenix landing by way of a feathered reentry configuration and parachutes so it returned to Earth much like a space capsule.

Comment: This needs references - at the very minimum links to the book (including the full title), or better yet scans of the chart in question.